# How to trim text and use it as parameter for next step in watir using ruby

Tags: ruby, split, trim

This may be very simple question but I am very new to ruby or any programming language. I want to trim some text and use it as parameter for next step. Can any one please write me code for doing this. I am testing a web application which is used in financial domain. I need to use the cvv2 and expiry date of card number which is generated in next step as parameter. The text which gets displayed on html is

```
CVV2 - 657  Expiry - 05/12 (mm/yy)
```

Now from the above text I should some how get only '657' and '0512' as value to use is in next step.
Request for urgent assistance.

Comment: please provide some code examples of what you tried and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If all your strings will be formatted like this, I suggest using regexp, using `String#gsub`. There's lots of places to learn about regexp if you don't already, and [rubular](http://rubular.com/) allows you to test it in your browser, with a short cheat sheet.

Answer (score 0):

To do it quickly you could use

```
card_details = "CVV2 - 657  Expiry - 05/12 (mm/yy)"
card_details = card_details.scan(/\d{2,}/)
cvv2 = card_details[0]
expiry = card_details[1] + card_details[2]
```

Probably better ways of doing it as I'm no expert, but you said urgent, so.

For getting the text out of the cell you could try (I don't use the original watir anymore, so I might not be able to remember this):

```
card_details = browser.td(:text => /CVV2/).text
```

If that doesn't work give this a try (actually on second thought TRY THIS ONE FIRST)

```
card_details = browser.cell(:text => /CVV2/).text
```

For these examples I'm assuming your browser object is called "browser".

Comment: Thanks you for this. Can you also suggest me how to get the text and store it as card_details as you have mentioned above. I realized it now that I do not know how to get th value and assign it to variable card-details. The html tag looks like this

<td width="100%" align="left" class="walletDispaly">
 CVV2 - 657  Expiry - 05/12 (mm/yy)

Comment: <td width="100%" align="left" class="walletDispaly">
Text -  CVV2 - 657  Expiry - 05/12 (mm/yy)

Comment: I've updated my answer to try and get you the details from the cell, but I don't use original watir anymore and I very rarely work with table cells, so text may not work as I expect it to.  If you're using watir-webdriver the .td method is the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

We can use regular expression to achieve the same,

```
> "CVV2 - 657  Expiry - 05/12 (mm/yy)".match(/\d{3}/)
=> "657"
>"CVV2 - 657  Expiry - 05/12 (mm/yy)".match(/\d+\/\d+/)
=> "05/12"
```